# Find coordinates inside a circle to form a triangle

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have the following given problem: I had a point outside the circle(the orange one) which is at (2,3) and based on a mathematical formula I found out the closest coordinate to the orange point in the circle(which is the blue point).

How can I now draw an equilateral triangle, with the blue point being one of the triangle vertexes, and length of each side is 0.02 units? The coordinate for the blue point is (3.505025253169417, 1.4949747468305832), the radius of the circle is 0.7

To make the required triangle I need the other two vertex coordinates? How to find them.

Can somebody help me in writing down pseudocode for this problem?
[image]

Comment: I don't think those lengths work. If the base is 0.04, and the other two sides are 0.02, then the triangle is actually just a line. See [triangle inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have now edited the question. Can you help?

Comment: Given an edge length and one vertex there are obviously infinite possible equilateral triangles. This means either you need more constraints if you think there should be a single correct solution, or you are free to pick any pair of points that you like which are 0.02 apart each-other and from the blue point. Say B(xB,YB) is the blue point, one possibility is to select the other points as C(xB+0.02,yB) and D((xB+xC)/2,yB-0.02*3^0.5/2)..  however this is only one of the infinite possible triangles. I think there are other constraints which are no t well expressed indeed.

Comment: [Compute the height (H) of the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zSSh.png). That gives you the distance from the blue point to the pink point. The distance from pink to green is 0.01, since it's half the base. So if the slope of the line from orange to blue is S, then you can compute the location of the pink point using the slope and the height. The slope of the line from pink to green is -1/S. Using that slope and a distance of 0.01, you can compute the location of the green point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of an equilateral triangle is `sqrt(3)/2` times its side length. Normalize the distance `b-a` to get a unit vector in the same direction. Adding it to `b` will be the center of the base. Exchanging the `x` and `y` of `c` and changing one sign, gets a perpendicular vector. Adding and subtracting this vector results in the base of the triangle.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 3])  # orange point
b = np.array([3.505025253169417, 1.4949747468305832])  # blue point
side = 0.2
height = side * np.sqrt(3) / 2
c = (b - a) / np.linalg.norm(b - a) * height
d = np.array([c[1], - c[0]]) / height * side / 2
e = b + c + d
f = b + c - d

plt.scatter(*b)
plt.scatter(*a)
plt.scatter(*(b + c), alpha=0.4)
plt.scatter(*e)
plt.scatter(*f)
triangle = np.array([b, e, f, b])
plt.plot(triangle[:, 0], triangle[:, 1], color='gold')
plt.fill(triangle[:, 0], triangle[:, 1], color='gold', alpha=0.3)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]